# Print Vector of Class Objects

Tags: c++, vector

I have three classes, a base class: Device, and two derived classes: SmartPhone, and Tablet.

Print is a virtual function that is redefined in the derived classes.
I would like to create an STL vector of devices (comprising of instances of smartphone and tablets), and then print names of the objects that are in the vector.

```
vector<unique_ptr<Device>> devices(3);
devices[0].reset(new SmartPhone(128, 8));
// memory size, screen size

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    devices[i].print();
}
```

I have an errors with my vector print implementation:

> class "std::unique_ptr>" has no member "print"

How can I call the print function of each object in the vector?

Device Base Class:

```
virtual void print(); {}
```

SmartPhone Derived Class:

```
void print();
```

-

```
void SmartPhone::print()
{
    printName();
    cout << "Memory: " << getMemory() << " Screen Size: " << getScreenSize();
}
```

Comment: The problem is in your `print()` not your for loop. Also you probably wanted to define operator << () instead anyways.

Comment: What's the declaration of `print`? Don't describe your code in prose, show a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a pointer, so you need to use pointer semantics:

```
devices[i]->print();
```

Operator `->` for `std::unique_ptr` returns the object it manages (i.e. `Device` instance) and you can call methods on it.

Operator `.` tries to call method on `std::unique_ptr` object, and this class doesn't have any method called `print`.

Also notice that the declaration of your method makes it impossible to use together with `std::cout`. To make it work, your function would have to be changed to overload of `operator <<` ([see the reference for more info](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators))

Answer (score -1):

You need to call the `print` function on each element in the devices vector not on the vector itself.

```
devices[i].print()
```

Comment: This is an (almost) good answer, but OP changed the question after it was posted...